# IFormFileCollection vs List<IFormFile>

Tags: c#

Could you recommend and explain benefits of two methods to receive multiple files in .Net Core. IFormFileCollection vs List. I couldn't find really good information near this topic.

Comment: Is something not working when you use one option or the other?

Comment: Do they work the same way or am I confusing something?

Comment: You can try it out. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0#upload-small-files-with-buffered-model-binding-to-physical-storage

Answer (score 2):

IFormFileCollection is an IEnumerable : [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfilecollection?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

It's just add two methods : GetFile(String) and GetFiles(String). But in term of data binding they act both the same.

I'll prefer using IFormFileCollection because it's implement the IReadOnlyList that make members read only